# Long tap doesn't work on Raspberry Pi touchscreen

Tags: angular, typescript, raspberry-pi3, hammer.js

I'm using HammerJS in an Angular app running in Electron on a Raspberry Pi with a touchscreen. I want my user to be able to tap for as long as they want (especially for old people).
Here is my Angular configuration:

```
export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  options = {
    domEvents: true,
    inputClass: Hammer.MouseInput,
    touchAction: 'auto'
  };
  overrides = {
    swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL },
    tap: {
      interval: 0,
      time: 5000
    }
  };
}
```

In my understanding, I should be able to tap for 5 sec and still have the tap event triggered. Unfortunately, nothing changes.
What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used `touchend` to make it work. The `tap` event just doesn't work for most people. The `time` option has no impact on user experience.